# How to save the data in LocalStorage by selecting the favorite button and also display it?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, local-storage

I am doing weather search project using a weather API.

The user should add the city and gets back a weather description and if it checks the box(favorite) the city data should be saved in the **LocalStorage** and be displayed into the cards(grid) on the page.

The page has 6 cards where the 1º display the search result and the others just will display the favorites.
I read a lot of things + videos about wrote and deleted codes and still stuck.

I am struggling in save the favorite city result in LocalStorage and do the loop and show in the display... like make a array=" ";(for cards) and store the array with the selected var favorite? that's part of my many logics

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#getWeather').click(function(){ //adding event
    var city = $("#city").val(); //store City into a var
    
    if(city != ' '){
        //Get the data and retrieve with ajax
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&units=metric' + '&appid=dc57bbc9d1642428d47d8c866bbacd87',
            type:"GET",
            datatype: "jsonp",
            success: function(data){
                var result = display(data);

                $("#show").html(result); //display result into card
                $("#city").val(''); //clean card
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("#error").text('Please add an city');


      }
    });

});

function display(data){
    return  "<h2>" + data.name + "</h2>" +
            "<h3>" + data.main.temp + "<h3>" +
            "<span>" + data.weather[0].main + "<span>";
           
}
```

### HTML

```
<!-- nav search box -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="city" name="city" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City Name" >
        </div>
            <button id="getWeather" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Search City</button>
        <div id="error" class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"></div>
    </form>
</nav>

<!-- card box (Results of research)-->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="fav-city-cb" value=" ">
                    </div> 
                        <div id="show" stytle="text-align: center"></div>
                        <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" > I am a button</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Cards which will store favorites -->
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="fav-city-cb" value=" ">
                    </div> 
                    <div style="text-align: center"><h2>Card2 Favorite goes here<h2></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="fav-city-cb" value=" ">
                    </div> 
                    <div style="text-align: center"><h2>Card3 and here<h2></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container-fluid padding">
        <div class="row padding">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="fav-city-cb" value=" ">
                        </div> 
                        <div style="text-align: center"><h2>Card1 and here<h2></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="fav-city-cb" value=" ">
                        </div> 
                        <div style="text-align: center"><h2>Card2 and here<h2></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-body" >
                        <div  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="fav-city-cb" value=" ">
                        </div> 
                        <div style="text-align: center"><h2>Card3 also here<h2></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

---

https://codepen.io/gtsasil/pen/aGxZxo

This is the code but not my trials. I made so much code that I got confused, so better no display in here.

Thanks for all possible help and explanations

Answer (score 0):

In your success function where you are displaying the data you can add

```
localStorage.setItem('favouriteCity', data.name)
```

That is assuming data.name is the city, if it isn't replace it with whatever is the city.

Then to retrieve it you can just use getItem, like this

```
$('#city-header').html( localStorage.getItem('favouriteCity') )
```

Replace that selector with wherever you want to display the city name obviously. You can check the values stored in local storage for a page in Chrome dev tools under the Application tab.

I edited your pen here to show it working, after you search there is a span that populates from local Storage https://codepen.io/calder12/pen/Gdarzj

Comment: hey man, thanks.. 

But I should only save if select the check box and not when do the search. So I do not save the city but the data in this case the display(data). Then I need to make a loop to display the new fav into Cards2 or cards3 etc..

Comment: like.
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
  var fav = $('#show').val();
  localStorage.setItem("favorite", test);
});

Comment: That's going to be a fairly complicated bit of code. You need to send the data to the local storage as an array, then check that array on page load to see if there is anything in it, then add cards based on that data. I might be able to mock up a working example a little later, but to be honest for future reference that much code is pretty outside the standard on SO. Just so you know and can avoid getting complained at in the future!

Comment: Thanks Rick,

I got another alternative that is working I notice it would be a lot of code for a entry level like me. Thanks for answering !!!

Comment: glad to hear you found a solution! I got really busy, so that works out well.